# postgres docker contanner on raspberrypi time aways wrong

Tags: postgresql, docker, time, raspberry-pi, timezone

postgresql on my rasbian aways have got wrong time!

but not the same with nginx contanner,

what's wrong with my docker?

Nginx:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ docker run -it -e TZ=Asia/Shanghai nginx date
Mon Oct 25 14:12:45 CST 2021
```

Postgres:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ docker run -it postgres:alpine date
Tue Jun 30 15:19:12 UTC 2071
```

Postgres localtime:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ docker run -it -e TZ=Asia/Shanghai -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro postgres:12 date
Thu 01 Jan 1970 08:00:00 AM CST
```

My docker info below:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.9
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.8
 Git commit:        c2ea9bc
 Built:             Mon Oct  4 16:06:55 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/arm
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.9
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.8
  Git commit:       79ea9d3
  Built:            Mon Oct  4 16:04:47 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.11
  GitCommit:        5b46e404f6b9f661a205e28d59c982d3634148f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.2
  GitCommit:        v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Comment: I have the same issue. I am using docker-compose. Each time I restart, the postgresql container has a different random system time (sometimes far in the future, other times in the past). Here is my database definition from docker-compose.yml:  database:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=myuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
      - POSTGRES_DB=teslamate
    volumes:
      - teslamate-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be an issue with the libseccomp2 library on Raspberry Pi. I was experiencing the same issues, and eventually resolved it by following the steps in this [thread](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/3253#issuecomment-956378676)

Add the following to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ testing main
```

Run `apt update`

Run `apt-get install libseccomp2/testing`

After running these updates the date/time should reflect that of your host. You may need to also mount `/etc/localtime` and `/etc/timezone` to get everything to match.

`docker run -it -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro --entrypoint /bin/sh postgres`

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      TZ: America/Chicago
      PGTZ: America/Chicago
      POSTGRES_DB: test
      POSTGRES_USER: testing
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
```